# How do I start workflow session only when the indicator file show up? (Informatica)

Tags: session, informatica, informatica-powercenter

What does this mean to start the session only when an indicator file show up for the workflow? Where do I create the text file and how do I insert it to the session? Also, what type of content should be in the text file? I'm quite new into informatica so I really need help... It is because everytime I want to start the session, I would right-click to start the workflow..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Event wait` taks and set it to wait for a file you're expecting. There is a downside: you can only monitor for a file with a predefined name, there are no wildcards allowed.

Here's more: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/event-wait-task-in-informatica/

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean to start the session only when an indicator file show up for the workflow?

This means there is a dependent file that must be present before the session in workflow is triggered.

> Where do I create the text file and how do I insert it to the session?

You should create the text file in a location on Informatica server that workflow can access. You will want to use an [event wait task](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/tasks/working-with-the-event-task/event-wait-tasks.html) placed prior to session. In event wait task, you'll specify the location and filename that must be present before event wait task succeeds.

> Also, what type of content should be in the text file?

The file can be blank since it is a trigger file.